# js google maps showing dark screen

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple code which would display the location on the google maps. But for some reasons its showing a dark screen. Any idea what's happening?

```
    <html>
  <head>
  <title> Using Google Maps API in PHP- InfoTuts </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>




    <div id="display_map" style="width:450px;height:350px; "></div> 

<div id="myad">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-9165168790934890";
/* top */
google_ad_slot = "6414226949";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script> 
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

this is the console:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please post your code, otherwise you will get no answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Google App Key?

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<your app key>&callback=<your endpoint>"></script>
```

Comment: yes i have it, but i couldn't find where i put it in my script. i try with your script but it's the seem problem.

Comment: Also you need allow your urls in Google console. look to my site map works well   [link](https://juliet.life/sitemap/)